# ev.target.children[0] is not an object

Tags: javascript

My Javascript is below.

If I don't insert  `ev.target.removeChild(ev.target.children[0]);`, it works. However, when I run above code, I get an error.

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.removeChild is not an object.
```

What should I do?

I'm making a board game. If player drag & drop a piece, the `<img>` of that piece moves.

```js
(function() {
  var allowDrop, drag, drop;

  window.allowDrop = allowDrop = function(ev) {
    return ev.preventDefault();
  };

  window.drag = drag = function(ev) {
    return ev.dataTransfer.setData("image", ev.target.id);
  };

  window.drop = drop = function(ev) {
    var data;
    ev.preventDefault();
    data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("image");
    ev.target.removeChild(ev.target.children[0]);
    return ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  };

}).call(this);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          <img></img>
        </td>
        <td id=" 2 " ondrop = "drop(event) " ondragover = "allowDrop(event)">
      <img></img>
    </td>
    ...
  </tr>
  <tr>
    ...
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, and that means that ev is not an object. Can you tell us what you are trying to achieve here may be can understand better.

Comment: Sounds like `ev.target` doesn't have any children.

Comment: FYI, `<img>` is a single tag, there's no `</img>`

Comment: I found the cause. I thought that I droped img on td, but in fact, I dropped it on img which is the td's child.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the target has any children before trying to remove it:

```
if (ev.target.firstChild) {
    ev.target.removeChild(ev.target.firstChild);
}
```

```js
(function() {
  var allowDrop, drag, drop;

  window.allowDrop = allowDrop = function(ev) {
    return ev.preventDefault();
  };

  window.drag = drag = function(ev) {
    return ev.dataTransfer.setData("image", ev.target.id);
  };

  window.drop = drop = function(ev) {
    var data;
    ev.preventDefault();
    data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("image");
    if (ev.target.firstChild) {
      ev.target.removeChild(ev.target.firstChild);
    }
    return ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  };

}).call(this);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <img></img>
    </td>
    <td id="2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <img></img>
    </td>
    ...
  </tr>
  <tr>
    ...
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```